# container-fluid class taking extra height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```html
<nav id="nav" class="navbar clearfix" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
               <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
                  <div class="navbar-header clearfix">
                     <!-- Logo -->
                     <!-- <div class="site-branding clearfix"> -->
                     <div class="site-logo">
                        <?php
                        the_custom_logo();
                        ?>
                     </div>
                     <div class="site-title clearfix"> <span>
    <?php echo "$lines[0] </br> $lines[1] $lines[2]";
                ?>
            </span> </div>
                     <!-- [END] .logo -->
                     <div class="burger-menu">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar">
                        <!-- <?php esc_html_e('Primary Menu', 'ohri'); ?> --><span class="sr-only">
                           <?php _e('Toggle navigation', 'ohri'); ?>
                        </span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- [END] .navbar-header -->
                  <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse clearfix" id="main-navbar">
                     <?php
                                /**
                                * Displays a navigation menu
                                */
                        echo do_shortcode('[menu name="main-menu"]');

                     ?>

                        <div class=" search-form clearfix">
                           <form class="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" role="search" tabindex="0">
                              <input type="button" class="search-submit " value="Search " />
                              <label>
                                 <input id="main-search-query s" class="search-input search_field_main" maxlength="50" type="search" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e(' Search ', 'ohri'); ?>" value="<?php  the_search_query(); ?>"> </label>
                              <input type="submit" class="search-trigger search_submit_main " value="Search "> </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <!-- [END] .navbar-collapse -->
               </div>
               <!-- [END] .container-fluid -->
            </nav>
```

[container-fluid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR31m.jpg) I have `div` with class `container-fluid` and I check all elements inside that `container-fluid` they are not taking any extra height although `div` with `container-fluid` class is taking extra height.

I have attached a picture as well. I have tried `max-height, min-height height` nothing is working.

```css
.navbar>.container-fluid {
     display: block;
     padding-right: 0px;
     
 }
 nav.navbar .collapse {

     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     position: relative;
     top: -140px;
     float: right;
     margin: 15px 15px 8px 0;
     /*padding: 10px;*/
     background-color: transparent;
     background-image: none;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
     overflow-x: visible;
     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     border-top: none;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }

 .menu-main-menu-container {
     position: relative;
     right: 80px;
 }
```

Comment: Please include some code. Also I don't think you attached the photo...

Comment: sorry I am new to this I am attaching a photo